# Two images with minipage

Tags: graphics, minipage

I would like to have side by side two images in latex using mini page. In order to do so i have the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[!tbp]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{imgs/fid_score.jpg}
  \caption{my caption 1.}
  \label{fig:1}
 \end{minipage}
 \hfill
 \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{imgs/is.png}
  \caption{my caption 2}
  \label{fig:2}
 \end{minipage}
 \caption{total caption}
 \end{figure}
```

My problem is that with the previous code I got three captions:

> Figure 1: my caption 1
>   Figure 2: my caption 3
>   Figure 3: total caption

Ideally, I would like to have Figure 1 and Figure 1 b. How can I do it in such a way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load the `subcaption` package and use this code:

```
\begin{figure}[!tbp]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{imgs/fid_score.jpg}
  \caption{my caption 1.}
  \label{fig:1}
 \end{subfigure}
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{imgs/is.png}
  \caption{my caption 2}
  \label{fig:2}
 \end{subfigure}
 \caption{total caption}\label{fig:total}
 \end{figure}
```

Comment: I modified it in such a way, now it works properly but I am facing another issue, both images even if they have the same exact size and there is not any white framing they are not depicted with the same size. How can I align them?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. How can the original images have the same size, be scaled by the same factor and not have the same size in the resulting .pdf? Also, align *how*? Horizontally?

Comment: It was only due to the different size of the caption between the two images.

Comment: In this case, you might be interested in the `floatrow` package, which has quite some tools for the alignment.